# adding headers in embedded jetty server

Tags: java, http-headers, jetty, zk, embedded-jetty

I'm checking security issue using OWASP ZAP and I have to resolve those two issues :

> "X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing"

and

> "Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set".

I'm working with ZK framework and an embed jetty server. I tried to add those headers to the jetty server but  the security tests are always failed

```
webAppContext.getServletHandler().getServletContext().setInitParameter("cacheControl", "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform");
webAppContext.getServletHandler().getServletContext().setInitParameter("Pragma", "no-cache");
webAppContext.getServletHandler().getServletContext().setInitParameter("Expires", "0");
```

and I did not found a way to change the `contentType` in Jetty like `text/html; charset=UTF-8; X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff`

Comment: Headers are only added on a per-request basis.  Are you needing this on specific requests (like just static content)? or all requests?

Comment: I need this for all the requests and response

Comment: Adding headers to requests would be usual, and those specific headers would be pointless at the point in time that the request has reached Jetty.  Adding those headers on all responses would also be invalid for many kinds of requests and responses (eg: not a GET request method, or a 200 OK response code)